# Selenium - how to locate value using dropdown using xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The dropdown HTML on the header looks like this, usually I can manage if there's id on list, but there are none

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown pt-1">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add Data</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu text-center">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?=site_url()?>buku/create">Book</a>
             <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url(); ?>pelanggan/create">User</a>
```

I tried using:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add Data')]")),5000).click();
currDate=new Date();
console.log(`${timeStart.getHours()}:${timeStart.getMinutes()}:${timeStart.getSeconds()} - Data added`);
```

But as I expected, it only clicked on the text, not the dropdown itself

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet ah sorry, localhost file/dummy project. but here's an image in my language (I modified the language on my post).  https://imgur.com/a/QwkiS7q

Comment: I have nothing to do with that image. I need to open that page and research what happens there with browser dev tools

Comment: "But as I expected, it only clicked on the text, not the dropdown itself" --  why do you expect that? Your xpath seems like it should find the `a` element *containing* that text. Also, that particular element does not seem to be present in the HTML you presented, so I'm not sure how to help with this.

Answer (score -1):

You try click on the dropdown list itself instead of drop down item.Once the drop down list opens then only you can use Search by Text and click on the drop down items.

in this case i would suggest to use below xpath:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add Data')]/parent::li")),5000).click();
```

or

using css :

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.nav-item.dropdown.pt-1")),5000).click();
```

if that also does not work you can dynamically change dropdown attribute using javascriptExecuter

```
document.querySelector('li.nav-item.dropdown.pt-1>a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle').setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true")
```

this will expand the drop down list by default. you don't have to click on the dropdown box.Then easily you can select elements from dropdown list.

it would be nice if you could provide the website url . if not hope this will give some sense how to handle this.